# How to add hyperlink to a google sheet cell using gspread in python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

There is a way to add hyperlink with gspread as below:

```py
sheet.update_cell(5, 1, '=HYPERLINK("www.google.com","google")')
```

But what I need to do is keep the url inside a variable or list (as there will be many urls) and then use the url from the variable. Something like:

```py
google_url = 'www.google.com'

sheet.update_cell(5, 1, '=HYPERLINK(google_url,"google")')
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

import hyperlink
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("influenceurs_35k-55k(08.07.20)").sheet1

data = sheet.get_all_records()

col = sheet.col_values(2)

insertRow = ["hello", 5, "red", "blue"]

sheet.delete_rows(14)

sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 14)

sheet.update_cell(14,1, "seyepapeseny@gmail.com".format("email"))

sheet.format("A14:b14")

Comment: You're missing the point. While you're updating the cell you're putting the email address directly in the parameter. What I have to do, first put the email id inside a variable and then give the variable as the parameter.